# Excel chart update issue

Tags: excel, formula

I am having trouble to update the Excel chart, which should be updated on a quarter basis; below is the formula(please note the *highlighted* "*" code which is the update that I am trying to apply)

```
=GSM!$E$3,GSM!$H$3,GSM!$K$3,GSM!$N$3,GSM!$Q$3,GSM!$T$3,GSM!$W$3,GSM!$Z$3,GSM!$AC$3,GSM!$AF$3,GSM!$AI$3,GSM!$AL$3,GSM!$AO$3,GSM!$AR$3,GSM!$AU$3,GSM!$AX$3,GSM!$BA$3,GSM!$BD$3,GSM!$BG$3,GSM!$BJ$3,GSM!$BM$3,GSM!$BP$3,GSM!$BS$3,GSM!$BV$3,GSM!$BY$3,GSM!$CB$3,GSM!$CE$3,*GSM!$CH$3*,GSM!$E$138,GSM!$H$138,GSM!$K$138,GSM!$N$138,GSM!$Q$138,GSM!$T$138,GSM!$W$138,GSM!$Z$138,GSM!$AC$138,GSM!$AF$138,GSM!$AI$138,GSM!$AL$138,GSM!$AO$138,GSM!$AR$138,GSM!$AU$138,GSM!$AX$138,GSM!$BA$138,GSM!$BD$138,GSM!$BG$138,GSM!$BJ$138,GSM!$BM$138,GSM!$BP$138,GSM!$BS$138,GSM!$BV$138,GSM!$BY$138,GSM!$CB$138,GSM!$CE$138,*GSM!$CH$138*
```

when I am trying to apply the above code it throws the following error:

> Series formula is too long. Reference is not valid.

Is there any way to shortcut/correct it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this probably belongs on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a series formula has 5 primary arguments:

```
=SERIES([series_name],[category_label],values,order,[size])
```

Where all those in braces are optional.
Now, if you are trying to graph a non-contiguous cells, you should wrap those cells in a parenthesis. Like this:

```
=SERIES(,(Sheet1!$A$3,Sheet1!$A$5,Sheet1!$A$7),(Sheet1!$B$3,Sheet1!$B$5,Sheet1!$B$7),1)
```

Note that it can be non-contiguous as long as it lies in the same column or row (like in your example).
If not, you should take on what @Skippy suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use a separate sheet (let's call it "RangeSheet") where you would set

A3 `=GSM!$E$3`
B3 `=GSM!$H$3`
C3 `=GSM!$K$3`
...
Z3 `=GSM!$CB$3`   Z3 `=GSM!$CB$3`
AA3 `=GSM!$CE$3`
AB3 `=GSM!$CH$3`

and

A138 `=GSM!$E$138`
B138 `=GSM!$H$138`
C138 `=GSM!$K$138`
etc

Then your series formula becomes something like

`=RangeSheet!$A$3:$AB$3,RangeSheet!$A$138:$AB$138`